# See if _REQUEST value is 0 or 1 or anything else

Tags: php, input, request

I am trying to see if a _REQUEST['abc'] value is either 1 or 0, or else set it to "na"

If I use intval(), then var=abc intval($abc) = 0, as does a blank value "?abc="

How can I tell if abc=0 or abc=1, else abc = na?

I've tried

```
if( intval( $inputs[ 'abc' ] ) !== 0 && intval( $inputs[ 'abc' ] ) !== 1 )
{
    $inputs[ 'abc' ] = 'na';
}
```

EDIT:

For transparency, my final solution was:

```
if( strval( $inputs['abc'] ) !== '0' && strval( $inputs['abc'] ) !== '1' )
            {
                $inputs['abc'] = 'na';
            }
```

So maybe my solution was a product of two, but thanks to all who helped me

Comment: Have you echo'd `$inputs['abc']` to see what it's ACTUALLY set to?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming by _REQUEST you meant $_REQUEST, then we might want to approach it like so:

```
    <?php
        // ASSIGN THE VALUE OF THE $_REQUEST GLOBAL TO $inputs
        $inputs     = $_REQUEST;

        // YOU MAY NOT NEED TO CAST TO INTEGER TYPE DURING THE CHECKS
        // ESPECIALLY SINCE 0 IS INVOLVED... THE BEST BET IS EVEN TO CAST ALL TO STRING...
        // SO WE FIRST CHECK THAT $inputs['abc'] IS NOT EQUAL TO THE STRING VALUE "0"
        if( ($inputs['abc'] . "") !== "0" ){
            // THEN AGAIN; WE CHECK THAT THE STRING VALUE OF $inputs['abc'] IS NOT "1"
            if( ($inputs['abc'] . "" ) !== "1" ) {
                // IF OUR CONDITION IS SATISFIED, WE GO AHEAD AND DO THE ASSIGNMENT: $inputs['abc'] = 'na' 
                $inputs['abc'] = 'na';
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: That works, I didn't think to convert int's to string's, too busy about thinking string's to int's... annoyingly, sometimes as much as I hate to admit it, loose-types are a pain, but thank you

Answer (score 3):

Instead if `intval` use `strval`, which converts your variable to string. And compare this value to string `'1'` or `'0'`:

```
if( strval( $inputs[ 'abc' ] ) !== '0' && strval( $inputs[ 'abc' ] ) !== '1' )
{
    $inputs[ 'abc' ] = 'na';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hardly ever typecast in PHP, just let loose comparison take care of things. Also, `in_array` has my preference over multiple conditions. Much easier to read and maintain imo.

So my code would look like this:

```
if (! in_array($inputs['abc'], [0,1])) {
    $inputs['abc'] = 'na';
}
```